# Как оповестить пользователя о не сохраненных данных

Tags: javascript

Ребят, приветствую.
Скажите пожалуйста, как реализовывается сообщение, если к примеру пользователь изменил 1 input формы, и уходит со страницы(или обновляет её) не нажав кнопку сохранить.
Как его остановить/оповестить о том, что данные не сохранились?

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return ('Все данные, которые вы ввели будут потеряны');};` а после сохранения `window.onbeforeunload = "";`

Comment: @splash58 только не везде сработает

Comment: @splash58 Это сработает, даже если поля не изменялись. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если честно, я вопрос не изучал :(ю себе когда-то сделал, прям сейчас и глянул :) - как раз на странице

Comment: @ДанилСысоев так включайте, когда что-то изменилось. и выключайте после сохранения

Comment: @splash58 , тю блин. Совсем туплю уже. Спасибо большое Вам за наводку.